# System chaincode vs user chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

It the hyperledger documentation, it's stated that when implementing some features is difficult or impossible then we use system chaincode to implement those features.

But, user chaincode uses "Go" which is Turing-complete language. So, it seems to me, everything can be implemented on it (unless its cost is prohibitively high but this is not defined anywhere in hyperledger documentation).

**Question** 1: What kind of operations is hard or impossible to implement in user chaincode?

**Question** 2: When do we use system chaincode?

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: What kind of operations is hard or impossible to implement
>   in user chaincode?

Operations that need access to native peer services like its communication layer, its Membership Service Provider (MSP) service, etc.
But also operations like computing a pre-image of a 1-way function, or operations that decide whether a given code stops on a given input.

> Question 2: When do we use system chaincode?
>   In 2 types of cases:

1. When you want your chaincode to be run inside the peer, i.e because of performance (user chaincode does lots of gRPC round trips)
2. When you want your chaincode to be able to access all types of services the peer can only provide via code imports and code references, and the shim API cannot provide them, such as communication layer, MSP layer, and others.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer!  However, they are a bit high level; especially, for those who want to implement some crypto. protocols on Hyperledger Fabric (including myself). So, given a complex crypto. protocol, how can I decide if I need to implement it on a system or user chaincode? Moreover, it would be great if you could provide a source so I can read it (I've already read the latest Fabric documentation released last week). Thanks again!

Comment: If your crypto protocol needs access to the private key of the peer, then it has to be a system chaincode.
Otherwise, you can do it with a user chaincode.

Can you elaborate a bit about the crpto you want to implement?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The protocol at a high level, will not be computationally very cheap. It uses crypto commitments, zero-knowledge and a variant of RSA signature. At the setup phase, it uses two clients private keys. Also, the nodes may want to work on some data provided in a smart contract and prove the correctness of their work (so the nodes have some secrets as well).  I'm wondering how in terms of computational and feasibility of operations we can determine what is possible or more efficient on system chaincode. Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain in general without knowing what you want to do. ping me on rocket-chat chat.hyperledger.org and you can explain better your use case.